# How to create a HashSet of custom data type in Java?

Tags: java, interface, hashset, user-defined-types

I want to create a HashSet of my own custom data type. I have implemented my custom data type as an Interface named `Pair`. Here are the codes I've come up with so far (full of errors of course ;) );

btw, the file Pair.java, containing `public class Pair` is in the same folder as Names.java; and I'm not using any IDEs, I'm using command prompts in CMD:

file `Pair.java`:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private T1 firstItem;
    private T2 secoundItem;

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 secound) {
        firstItem = first;
        secoundItem = secound;
    }

    public T1 first() {
        return firstItem;
    }

    public T2 secound() {
        return secoundItem;
    }
}
```

file `Names.java`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Names {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Pair<String, Integer>> names = new HashSet<Pair<String, Integer>>();
            names.add(Pair("Name1", 1));
        names.add(Pair("Name2", 2));
        names.add(Pair("Name3", 3));
        names.add(Pair("Name4", 4));
        System.out.println("The number of names is " + names.size());

        for(Pair P : names) {
                System.out.println(P.first() + " : " + P.secound());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `new Pair("a", "b");`? :)

Comment: Also your `Pair` class should override the the methods `hashCode()` and `equals()`. See the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for the contract of hashCode with respect to equals.

Comment: Why not just use a `HashMap`?

Comment: I'm trying to learn HashSet, but I'm not sure if what I want can be  done using HshSet.

Comment: @PetrMensik : thank you, that was a pretty noob mistake, wasn't it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
names.add(Pair("Name1", 1));
```

to

```
names.add(new Pair("Name1", 1));
```

You  need the keyword `new` every time you create an object.

Answer (score -2):

You need to call javac with all *.java files. It does not look for other files in the current directory.

Comment: According to the documentation for javac, "...  If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory. ..."

Comment: You're right. My bad. Sorry for misguidance.
I did not notice lack of `new` because of doing much Scala now where it is used very rarely. So the incomplete list of source files seemed to be the problem at first.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I should provide a list of source files.

Comment: No, it was my mistake. You don't have to if all of them are in one directory as David Wallace pointed out. Read more on classpaths in Java so you won't give such a stupid answers as I did ;)